# How to tell if browser/tab is active

Tags: javascript, jquery

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

I have a function that is called every second that I only want to run if the current page is in the foreground, i.e. the user hasn't minimized the browser or switched to another tab. It serves no purpose if the user isn't looking at it and is potentially CPU-intensive, so I don't want to just waste cycles in the background.

Does anyone know how to tell this in JavaScript?

Note: I use jQuery, so if your answer uses that, that's fine :).

Comment: +1 would like to know the answer. my concern is not CPU-intensive but instead bandwidth and server intensive.

Comment: If you want a Jquery plugin.. https://github.com/keithhackbarth/jquery-window-active

Comment: **Update:** As of 2013 all major browsers provide support for the so-called [visiblity API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/User_experience/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API). See here for a sample: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19519701/603003

Comment: I think the best sample is at http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/ put on your headphones and play and you will see (after you start the video) that the implementation is spot-on.

Comment: Use `document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", onchange);` see https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/1066234 and https://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/

Answer (score 382, accepted):

You would use the `focus` and `blur` events of the window:

```
var interval_id;
$(window).focus(function() {
    if (!interval_id)
        interval_id = setInterval(hard_work, 1000);
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    clearInterval(interval_id);
    interval_id = 0;
});
```

---

To Answer the Commented Issue of "Double Fire" and stay within jQuery ease of use:

```
$(window).on("blur focus", function(e) {
    var prevType = $(this).data("prevType");

    if (prevType != e.type) {   //  reduce double fire issues
        switch (e.type) {
            case "blur":
                // do work
                break;
            case "focus":
                // do work
                break;
        }
    }

    $(this).data("prevType", e.type);
})
```

Click to view [Example Code Showing it working (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/meehanman/40edh944/)

Comment: does that works? tested? that simple?

Comment: @thephpdeveloper: Sure. If you have firebug, try a simple `console.log('test')` call for either event.

Comment: Works great. I start an interval in focus and stop it on blur.

Comment: It doesn't work on FF 4 and higher :/

Comment: This answer is not optimal because `focus` and `blur` events can often fire more than one time in the browser for each conceptual Focus or Blur action taken by the user, in which case the client will start doing `hard_work` on more than one interval, basically simultaneously.

Comment: @jon-z, how about that adjustment?

Comment: i for example see that blur does not fire up when i switch between applications, but does work when i switch between tabs on Mac OS, and on firefox/chrome/safari ...

Comment: I've read elsewhere that `onmousemove` could be a viable replacement for `focus`.

Comment: @MichaelRobinson Maybe for maximized/fullscreen tabbed browsers. It may still fire in Internet Explorer (http://www.bit-tech.net/news/bits/2012/12/13/ie-bug-cursor/1), although the focus is on some other application.

Comment: But what if the user switches tab whilst the page loads, before `$(window)focus/blur` has been called? Depending on your use case, this might mess up the callback status, and any background job? (For example, if you start the background job on page load — but `blur` never happens, because the user switched tabs before `$(window).blur` was registered?)

Comment: This also doesn't work if the user clicks an iframe within the page.

Comment: You saved my day. The Switch case with blur/focus worked perfectly in desktop and ios devices.

Comment: try http://daniemon.com/tech/webapps/page-visibility/ works better I think

Answer (score 517):

In addition to [Richard Simões](https://stackoverflow.com/users/91768/richard-simoes) answer you can also use the [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/).

```
if (!document.hidden) {
    // do what you need
}
```

> This specification defines a means for site developers to
> programmatically determine the current visibility state of the page in
> order to develop power and CPU efficient web applications.

### Learn more (2019 update)

- [All modern browsers are supporting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden#Browser_compatibility) `document.hidden`
- http://davidwalsh.name/page-visibility
- https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility
- Example pausing a video when window/tab is hidden
   https://web.archive.org/web/20170609212707/http://www.samdutton.com/pageVisibility/

Comment: +1 for giving an answer which doesn't rely on jQuery. This also seems like the best answer in the long run, as browsers move toward supporting W3C standards. David Walsh's example worked for me on Chrome and Firefox, but not Safari.

Comment: Visibility and focus are completely different things.

Comment: I have a websocket spitting data multiple times per second. As soon as I pick another tab the memory usage skyrockets! Wrapping my code between this answer keep stuff under control. Many thanks!

Comment: Page visibility API detects if the browser is visible, e.g not minimized or completely covered by another window. It doesn't detect the case where the window is visible but an another window is active.

Comment: FYI:  http://caniuse.com/#search=Page%20Visibility

Comment: Tnx 4 this clean solution, however, you maybe would like to consider checking also document.webkitHidden, mozHidden, msHidden
as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19519701/4572425

Comment: @ckknight do you mind changing the accepted answer to this one?  This updated answer is the one we should be using in 2019

Comment: “Page Visibility Level 2 replaces the first version of `[PAGE-VISIBILITY]` and includes: …… `Document.hidden` is historical. **Use `Document.visibilityState` instead.**”

Comment: [Safari is supported now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/hidden#Browser_compatibility) `document.hidden` including Safari

Comment: @JuhaSyrjälä That's a good thing for most people, if it's visible then data should still be polling imho unless you got some different use case, especially if you're referring to multiple monitors :|

Comment: @КонстантинВан Only the W3C could create a draft with a recommendation that **voids and replaces itself** with another recommendation from the very same draft.

Comment: @andreszs I see.

Comment: in 2022, use `document.visibilityState` see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState

Answer (score 181):

I would try to set a flag on the `window.onfocus` and `window.onblur` events.

The following snippet has been tested on Firefox, Safari and Chrome, open the console and move between tabs back and forth:

```
var isTabActive;

window.onfocus = function () { 
  isTabActive = true; 
}; 

window.onblur = function () { 
  isTabActive = false; 
}; 

// test
setInterval(function () { 
  console.log(window.isTabActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
}, 1000);
```

Try it out [here](http://jsbin.com/ulize3).

Comment: example is awesome. any idea about IE?

Comment: I can confirm that it works great in IE7, haven't tested beyond that, this is the best answer and it was also the first answer among all the answers that are functionally the same, vote it up!

Comment: I also like this simple example.  I have fixed a small typo and added page feedback + jquery to see what is happening without the console. http://jsbin.com/ulize3/80

Comment: for some reason isActive is always false on Chrome?

Comment: @sri ... not sure if this is due to a Chrome update a year later, but isActive==false for the console itself, you have to click back in the main window.

Comment: Actually, the reason it's always false on Chrome is because the `console.log` use `window.isActive`. Remove the `window.` part or add it everywhere. I also think `isActive` should be initialized as true for better results.

Comment: what is the reason why a piece of code that does not work gets 100 votes?

Comment: Why you use `setInterval` function? you could make a `custom event` and just `dispatch` it.

Comment: Won't work if you have iframes

Comment: In Chrome you do have to click inside the page once it seems to make this work. Firefox has no such requirement.

Answer (score 19):

Using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    window.isActive = true;
    $(window).focus(function() { this.isActive = true; });
    $(window).blur(function() { this.isActive = false; });
    showIsActive();
});

function showIsActive()
{
    console.log(window.isActive)
    window.setTimeout("showIsActive()", 2000);
}

function doWork()
{
    if (window.isActive) { /* do CPU-intensive stuff */}
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer of the whole lot, should have gotten much higher up votes.

Comment: downvoted for using jquery, sorry :), jquery wasn't mentioned in the question, and it's just awful

Answer (score 10):

All of the examples here (with the exception of rockacola's) require that the user physically click on the window to define focus.  This isn't ideal, so `.hover()` is the better choice:

```
$(window).hover(function(event) {
    if (event.fromElement) {
        console.log("inactive");
    } else {
        console.log("active");
    }
});
```

This'll tell you when the user has their mouse on the screen, though it still won't tell you if it's in the foreground with the user's mouse elsewhere.

Comment: Good outside the box thinking; however, it wouldn't work very well if you were trying to figure out how long a user stays on a page. Also, `hover` is not a valid option for mobile browsers. To be fair though, I have no idea if the `focus` or `blur` event binding would work on mobile devices.

Comment: also, hover depends on a mouse move. if the tab was entered using a keyboard shortcut, then the hover is probably not triggered.

Answer (score 9):

If you are trying to do something similar to the Google search page when open in Chrome, (where certain events are triggered when you 'focus' on the page), then the hover() event may help.

```
$(window).hover(function() {
  // code here...
});
```