# Is there any way to detect that window is currently active in IE8?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, tabs

Is there any way to detect that the window is currently active (is being shown on active tab/window) in IE8?

I know there are events like `onfocusin`/`onfocus` - but this is not a perfect solution, since the window must also receive focus for the event to be fired - so this does not work when the user just switches the tabs without touching the window itself.

I believe there has to be some simple, elegant solution for such ordinary use-case.

Comment: The best way to do this is by using the Page Visibility API. However, this API is not available in older browsers. I’ve written a jQuery plugin that uses the best API available to detect if the page is visible or not: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9634295/96656

Answer (score 16):

I’ve written a jQuery plugin that does this: http://mths.be/visibility It gives you a very simple API that allows you to execute callbacks when the page’s visibility state changes.

It does so by using the [**the Page Visibility API**](http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/) where it’s supported, and falling back to good old `focus` and `blur` in older browsers.

**Demo:** http://mathiasbynens.be/demo/jquery-visibility

This plugin simply provides two custom events for you to use: `show` and `hide`. When the page visibility state changes, the appropriate event will be triggered.

You can use them separately:

```
$(document).on('show', function() {
  // the page gained visibility
});
```

…and…

```
$(document).on('hide', function() {
  // the page was hidden
});
```

Since most of the time you’ll need both events, your best option is to use an events map. This way, you can bind both event handlers in one go:

```
$(document).on({
  'show': function() {
    console.log('The page gained visibility; the `show` event was triggered.');
  },
  'hide': function() {
    console.log('The page lost visibility; the `hide` event was triggered.');
  }
});
```

The plugin will detect if the Page Visibility API is natively supported in the browser or not, and expose this information as a boolean (`true`/`false`) in `$.support.pageVisibility`:

```
if ($.support.pageVisibility) {
  // Page Visibility is natively supported in this browser
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I checked the web and it seems that Page Visibility API is included in IE10. It seems that for older versions, we have to stick to good-old-not-very-well-working blur/focus :)

Comment: Also this is not working if user switches another program when on your page. Just works with switching between tabs.

Comment: For a plugin that is cross-browser and deals with "issues" that arise using `.blur|.focus`, try checking out the answer here -> [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active#answer-16043687)

Comment: @SpYk3HH The above plugin is cross-browser compatible and doesn’t have any known false positives. Do you know of any bugs in my plugin? If so, please report them.

Comment: My bad. I thought I noticed use of `blur` and `focus`, and yes, you'll have issues with those 2.  Aside from dealing with possible "double fire" that tends to happen with focus, those methods alone end up in non-positive reactions when simply clicking another program into focus. However, I haven't fully tested yours. I'll do that now. As for @xecute comment, it shouldn't blur when bringing another prog to focus. What if you blur hides values on a page and you need to use calculator?

Comment: @MathiasBynens This looks great -- I'd like to give it a try. I see it uses an event model; is it possible to simply check the current visibility status when another event happens? I have a chat feature that I'd like to have play a sound when a new message comes in, only when the application window is not visible. Thanks!

Comment: I was really hopeful this would work for my use case. Unfortunately the demo at https://mathiasbynens.be/demo/jquery-visibility only works when switching between tabs in the same browser window, not to other browser windows or other programs. Confirmed in Chrome 73.0.3683.103 (Official Build) (64-bit) and Firefox 66.0.3 (64-bit) on Windows.

Answer (score 2):

```
var isActive = false;
function onBlur() {
    isActive = false;
};
function onFocus(){
    isActive = true;
};

if (/*@cc_on!@*/false) { // check for Internet Explorer
    document.onfocusin = onFocus;
    document.onfocusout = onBlur;
} else {
    window.onfocus = onFocus;
    window.onblur = onBlur;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", () => { 
    if (document.visibilityState === 'visible') alert("Hello again"); 
});
```

See [Page Visibility API on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API) for more information.

Comment: See also: [visibilityState on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/visibilityState).

Answer (score 2):

Using the browser default [Page Visibility API](https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-page-visibility-20110602/).

```
function isPageHidden(){
    if (typeof(document.hidden) === 'boolean') return document.hidden;
    if (typeof(document.msHidden) === 'boolean') return document.msHidden;
    if (typeof(document.webkitHidden) === 'boolean') return document.webkitHidden;
    if (typeof(document.mozHidden) === 'boolean') return document.mozHidden;
    else return undefined;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a simple [task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760328/1113435) to achieve using jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    window.isActive = true;
    $(window).focus(function() { this.isActive = true; });
    $(window).blur(function() { this.isActive = false; });
});
```

The global isActive variable determines wether the tab/window is acive.

Comment: Unfortunately, it’s not that simple. Try this in IE — the event handler will be called for every click on the document, which is not very efficient. See [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9634295/96656) for an optimized solution.

Comment: For a plugin that is cross-browser and deals with "issues" that arise using `.blur|.focus`, try checking out the answer here -> [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active#answer-16043687)

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

    // Adapted slightly from Sam Dutton
    // Set name of hidden property and visibility change event
    // since some browsers only offer vendor-prefixed support
    var hidden, state, visibilityChange; 
    if (typeof document.hidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "hidden";
        visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
        state = "visibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.mozHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "mozHidden";
        visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
        state = "mozVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.msHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "msHidden";
        visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
        state = "msVisibilityState";
    } else if (typeof document.webkitHidden !== "undefined") {
        hidden = "webkitHidden";
        visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
        state = "webkitVisibilityState";
    }
    // Add a listener that constantly changes the title
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function() {
        document.title = document[state];
    }, false);

    // Set the initial value
    document.title = document[state];

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

To check window is currently active or not use:

```
document.hasFocus();
```

It will return `true` if window is currently active, otherwise `false`.

To check window is currently visible or not use:

```
document.visibilityState;
```

It has two state, `visible` and `invisible`.