# Check if site is in foreground

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreground

I would like to check if my website is in foreground with JavaScript. But don't answer before reading everything because you would directly say to me that I should do [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cK3NU/):

```
$(window)
    .focus(function() {
        console.log("focus");
    })
    .blur(function() {
        console.log("blur");
    });​
```

But the problem is that I've got an iframe from a third party on my page and if the user clicks on the iframe the window blur event gets fired but the user is acctualy still on my page. I tried to fix this by checking [if `document.activeElement` is an iframe on blur](http://jsfiddle.net/cK3NU/1/):

```
$(window)
    .focus(function() {
        console.log("focus");
    })
    .blur(function() {
        console.log("blur");
        if (document.activeElement.tagName.toLowerCase() == "iframe") {
            console.log("still focus");
        }
    });​
```

The problem here is that I'm not able to check if the page is not in foreground anymore when a user clicks on the iframe first and then on another application.

So how can I check if the site is in foreground when it got an iframe in it?

Comment: Maybe you could use [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1060008/1331430).

Comment: Thx this would cover the problem for the modern browsers but I also need IE8 support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Page Visibility API](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-page-visibility-20110602/).

> This specification defines a means for site developers to
> programmatically determine the current visibility state of the page in
> order to develop power and CPU efficient web applications.

### Learn more

- http://davidwalsh.name/page-visibility
- https://developers.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility

### **Example**

- http://www.samdutton.com/pageVisibility/

Comment: This would cover the problem for the modern browsers but I also need IE8 support.

Comment: Did you heard about graceful degradation? http://stackoverflow.com/a/9634295/294076

Comment: No but what that guy is doing is awesome. The source really looks like that it should work but I haven't tested it yet.