# mousemove is triggered once when mouse enters inactive browser window (Chrome)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

1. Open dev tools console.
2. Exec this code:

   ```
   window.addEventListener("mousemove", function() { console.log("moved!") });
   ```
3. Activate any **another** window.
4. Move mouse into browser window (but **DO NOT** put focus in).
5. Look in console.

**In FF**: nothing there.

**In Chrome**: there is one "moved!" message.

So in inactive window Chrome triggers exactly one `mousemove` event when mouse **enters** window, and then ignores any following movements.

Is this a bug?

And how to manage this? I can detect that mouse has left a browser window, with `toElement` prop of `mouseout` event. But how to detect whether window is currently active?

---

My env:

Chrome 46.0.2490.80

Firefox 41.0

MacOS Yosemite 10.10.5

Comment: What version of FF / Chrome are you using?  I see exactly the same behaviour in Chrome 46.0.2490.80m and FF 41.0.1 - and in each I see multiple "moved!" messages appearing in the console when the mouse is over the inactive browser window.

Comment: Chrome 46.0.2490.80, Firefox 41.0. My fault, I didn't say that it's on MacOS ( Yosemite 10.10.5 )

Comment: I don't know what expected behaviour is; but you might want to check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9632741/javascript-is-there-any-way-to-detect-that-window-is-currently-active-i-e-is/9634295#9634295) which discusses a jQuery plugin that gives you a show/hide event that uses the new Page Visibility API or falls back to the `blur`/`focus` events where that is not available.  Perhaps that will serve your needs.

Comment: still an issue in chrome 78 (mac os)

Answer (score 0):

I am seeing the same behavior in Chrome 107 on Mac OS 13.0 Ventura.  Here is my workaround.

```
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(){
    if(document.hasFocus()){
        console.log("moved!")
    }
});
```