# Javascript to detect if user changes tab

Tags: javascript, html

I am writing a webpage for online quiz. The basic requirement I have is that it must fire an event(stopping the quiz) if the user changes tabs or opens a news window even without minimizing their browser, i.e if the person is attempting to see the answer from some other window/tab. How can I do that?

**Note :** Try to avoid including a bleeding edge HTML5 feature in your answer because I want the feature to be supported by all major browsers currently.

Comment: Well certainly change in tab can be detected by using Javascript as far as i know.What i wanted to know is, if the change in focus of the window like opening a new browser can be detected!

Comment: You won't detect if it happens in another browser window.

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You can determine if a tab or window is active by attaching a blur / focus event listener to window.

in jQuery it would be

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    //do something
});

$(window).blur(function() {
    //do something
});
```

quoted from this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760268/680578

Comment: Would also fire for just losing focus on the window, but the window is still visible.

Comment: Will it be able to detect if the user launches new window/browser without minimizing quiz window?

Comment: If a new popup occurs, there will be a loss in focus to the current window, wouldn't there?

Comment: you also get a false positive when clicking on an iframe in that page.

Comment: non-jQuery version: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69509921/2336212

Answer (score 93):

In 2022 you can use an event listener with the `visibilitychange` event:

```js
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", (event) => {
  if (document.visibilityState == "visible") {
    console.log("tab is active")
  } else {
    console.log("tab is inactive")
  }
});
```

Comment: While the 'Page Visibility API' mozilla docs don't reference this specifically, I tried this approach to check if a User has logged out on another browser tab and, if so, then updates the displayed login info when the User comes back to a tab. It seems to work well. Is this the correct method to check login status or is there a better way?

Comment: not working for me

Answer (score 37):

If you are targeting browsers that support it, you can use the Page Visibility API available in HTML5.  It doesn't directly detect tab changes, per-say, but visibility changes.  Which would include (but not limited to) tab changes.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

Comment: This is a handy API however it should be noted that at this time (March 6, 2015) there are some limitations: `Alt` + `Tab` (e.g. app switching on of any kind) doesn't register on Windows for Firefox/Chrome/IE10.  Switching tabs within each browser does work just fine though. On iOS though app switching or device locking **does** trigger a visibility change.

Answer (score 31):

Best native function hands down, no jQuery.

```
document.hasFocus
```

Check the pen, check what happens when you go to the link and back to the codepen tab.

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/Yxxzdj

Comment: Seems to work for me in Opera, FireFox, Safari and Chrome. Haven't tested in others.

Comment: This demo checks for visibility every 200ms and is not ideal in terms of battery use. The Visibility API is event based and works down to IE10 and even on mobile, so I would strongly recommend you use that.

Comment: [has good browser support](https://caniuse.com/#search=hasFocus)

Comment: greate and simple

Comment: @UmairMohammad No need to test yourself to ensure compatibility: https://caniuse.com/?search=hasFocus

Answer (score 8):

window `onfocus` and `onblur` work just fine:

```
window.onfocus = function (ev) {
    console.log("gained focus");
};

window.onblur = function (ev) {
    console.log("lost focus");
};
```

Comment: This has the advantage over 'visibilitychange' event that it is triggerred after browser's window gained / lost focus while 'visibilitychange' works only on tab switching

Comment: This won't work though if say the code is inside of a iframe and the user clicks the main page. It will cause it to pause still

Comment: This relies on them doing something in the window to gain focus first. Or, else, you'd need to force focus on an element in the window on page load.

Answer (score 5):

With jQuery:

```
$(window).on('focus', function () {

});

$(window).on('blur', function () {

});
```

`$().focus` & `$().blur` are deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

Working on a similar project. This worked the best. On the highest level component which wouldn't normally rerender, add:

```
  setInterval( checkFocus, 200 );

  function checkFocus(){
    if(document.hasFocus()==false){
      //Do some checking and raise a red flag if this runs during an exam.
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I needed something like this and it seems this behavior is slightly different on each browser.

```
    if (document.hidden !== undefined) { // Opera 12.10 and Firefox 18 and later support     
      visibilityChange = "visibilitychange";
    } else if (document.mozHidden !== undefined) {      
      visibilityChange = "mozvisibilitychange";
    } else if (document.msHidden !== undefined) {      
      visibilityChange = "msvisibilitychange";
    } else if (document.webkitHidden !== undefined) {      
      visibilityChange = "webkitvisibilitychange";
    } else if (document.oHidden !== undefined) {      
      visibilityChange = "ovisibilitychange";
    }
    
    document.addEventListener(visibilityChange, function(event) {
      handleVisibilityChange();
    }, false);
```

I have an example you can check:
https://jsfiddle.net/jenol/4g1k80jq/33/