# How to check active tab in JavaScript/jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to run a function whenever a browser tab is active/selected.

How do I do it using JavaScript/jQuery?

Comment: Check this thread:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338704/javascript-to-detect-if-user-changes-tab

Comment: @Hazaart I have created this code but it keeps popping out 'focus' & 'blur' couple times whenever the page loads. I don't know whats wrong.

$(window).focus(function(){  
  alert('focus');    
});

$(window).blur(function(){  
  alert('blur');    
});

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can use the Page Visibility API ? The specification is at http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-page-visibility-20110602/

"This specification defines a means for site developers to programmatically determine the current visibility state of the page in order to develop power and CPU efficient web applications."

There is also a handy wrapper library for it - Visibility.js at https://github.com/ai/visibility.js

```
Visibility.onVisible(function () {
    // do something 
});
```

Comment: thanks. I have used this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API