# Detect URl Bar click event or user typing in Browser address bar with Jquery/java-script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a project where I need to Interact with browser Url bar. I mean I need too detect event with jquery/JS as soon as user clicks on address bar or type in there or if user clicks on another tab so to use with with callback and do the stuff. I know the browser is a OS app and has its own control but is there a way to accomplish this? Right now I am just detecting if user leaves Html from upper position.

Here is the code

```
co$(window).mouseleave(function(e){
    if(e.pageY<5)
    {
        //do stuff;
    }
});
```

Any thoughts will be appreciated

Comment: Whatever feature you are trying to implement - it seems like a bad idea to react or rely on things the user may does outside of your web page. If you really want to do that you'd need to create a browser plugin.

Comment: Thanks mate for Lead and i guess Browser plugin for this requirement can not be created in client or server web scripting languges any idea on this

Comment: Maybe something like this is sufficient: [detect if user changes tab](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10338754/897024).

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, you cannot tell when the user is interacting with the address bar.

Comment: So there is no way to detect if user actually clicked on browser address bar?

Comment: No, all you know is that their mouse left the browser window.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to handle this is using `$(window).bind('beforeunload', function (e) { your code here  });` But again it will not tell you which key is pressed. It will only gets called upon reload the page, refresh the page and browser close.