# run function while user is typing a url

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I want to run a function in a chrome extension while the user is typing a url.
The best option is to run the function on every key pressed on typing the url.

Any ideas?

Comment: Err do you have any code to show already? You need to post what you have tried. jsfiddle would be a good place for this.

Comment: The best approach for this that I know is a content script.
However a content script runs when a new page is loaded.
What I want is to call a function while the user is stil typing a url.
Unfortunately there is no code yet

Comment: see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18640449/1238244 You can write a function to run if someone is typing in a form field. But the address bar is outside of the document. Although I don't know if there is more flexibility with a chrome extensions.

Comment: I had a quick look here too: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-chrome-extension%5D+function+address+bar

Comment: @lharby Never suggest jsfiddle as a good place to post code for SO. [This is specifically discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code). Relevant code must be present in the question itself - jsfiddle can only be a secondary tool to demonstrate.

Comment: @Xan ok thanks for that. I do really like jsfiddle (prefer it to the code generator on SO) but I take your point. I was asking for code to be shown in the question.

Comment: @lharby Oh, don't get me wrong, SO's snippet mechanism is _bad_. It's just important to emphasize that code but be _also_ present in the question if you're using a fiddle.

Comment: Very unlikely that you will achieve this. You can detect changes on a page but not in the address bar.