# I want to display a message when I switch tabs in a browser. How do I go about it?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to make a webpage that helps you concentrate on your work by giving you points while you are on a webpage. 
I need something to display a message saying "You lost" or something like that when someone switches tabs . 
Being fairly new to web design, I'm unable to get this. Can someone please help?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect if browser tab is active or user has switched away](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19519535/detect-if-browser-tab-is-active-or-user-has-switched-away)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Questions seeking help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself and show effort. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to detect if user changes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338704/javascript-to-detect-if-user-changes-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using **window.onblur** event.The onblur event occurs when an object loses focus.Object in this case would be **window**

use this code snippet :

```
window.onblur = function () { 
  alert('trying to switch tabs eh !'); 
};
```

**EDIT** : see this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/winnysmartguy/zg8tufp0/) for a working demo, i've tested on chrome !

Comment: Thanks a lot! But since I'm just a newbie to js, could you please tell me a bit more how to use it?

Comment: I have now included a js fiddle , have a look !

Comment: Thanks Ankit! This is what I was looking for! Our main coder just switched sides and we're just left with some design artists now . Really needed this!

Answer (score 0):

You can attach to your window a focus or a blur event in jquery :

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    // your actions
});
```

But it's only on your website... You can build a browser extension if you wana check every pages.

Answer (score 0):

Pure JS, all browsers, hasFocus()

```
if ( document.hasFocus()
```

Check the link what happens when you open a new page with the button:-)

https://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/Yxxzdj