# Detect when tab is slowed down

Tags: javascript, html, websocket

I'm making a HTML5 game (with WebSockets) and frequent health bar updates are delivered. When I go to another application and return to the game later, all these updates are applied at once, so the health bar just goes up/down constantly for 30 seconds.

I believe that this is due to the browser giving the tab less processing time because it isn't active (so then the packets all queue up and are processed when I re-visit the tab or window).

Is there any good way of telling when a tab is slowed down like this? I'd like to detect this so that the game can automatically pause and stop receiving (then useless) packets.

This question is different from the [one linked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008) because when a user switches tabs, the CPU time of that tab isn't immediately reduced to a tiny amount. For example, I can quickly switch tabs to look at reddit and come back after a few seconds without an issue of packet build-up.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript to detect if user changes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338704/javascript-to-detect-if-user-changes-tab)