# Message for Browser Tab

Tags: javascript

I want to add a message for example: If the user leaves the browser tab, the message "Looks like you're gone ..." should appear. When the user returns to the page, change the message to "Good to be back".

Is it possible to do something like this?

Comment: Yes. Show us your code, and we will help you

Comment: Well the code it's not much... Just html with some multiple div and css, so is it important that I add it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript to detect if user changes tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10338704/javascript-to-detect-if-user-changes-tab)

Answer (score 1):

Crate an `eventListener` on your window, with the `load` event, and simply show an alert.

And create an event on your `window` called `onbeforeunload` ([more info about the event)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onbeforeunload.asp), where you show an alert while leaving the page.

**Note:** `onbeforeunload` won't work in this snippet, but try putting inside your code.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (event) =>{

    alert("Looks like you are back");

});

window.onbeforeunload = function() {
          alert("Looks like you want to leave");
      };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)

Answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63695199/8236182)