# Is it possible to check if the user is trying to exit the page on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone

Is it possible to check if the user is trying to exit the page on iPhone via Javascript?

So basically when the user swipes up the home button and the Browser Window is shown in the app gallery mode? Is there an event for that?

Comment: you should try some of the solutions in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10338704/17308201).

Answer (score -1):

No there is not in my knowledge.
I don't think there is a way we can see if a person is trying to get out of a Javascript page in an iOS software.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).