# How to continuously execute Javascript function when part of HTML is currently visible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, dom-events

I want to continuously execute specific Javascript function only when part of HTML document is visible. That implies stopping the execution of function when that part is not visible again.

Getting out of visible scope means that element is out by:

- scrolling out (either vertical or horizontal)
- changing to some other browser tab
- shutting down tab/window/entire browser.

Example code:
I have HTML with a style to make sure that I have div main (entire page) and div target that is on my screen (1920 X 1080) below visible scope:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Title</title>
<style type="text/css">
    #main{
        height: 2300px;
    }
    .target{
        border: 1px solid black;
        position: relative;
        top:1000px;
        width:150px;
        height: 150px;
    }
</style>
<script scr="js/jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="main">
        <div class="target"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What is the JS/Jquery code that will order:

**when div.target is currently visible trigger execution of my_function()**

**when div.target is scrolled out or tab is changed, stop execution of my_function()**
?

Comment: I'd say continuously executed scripts will throw an error after a time. Also it's not possible to scroll page, if a script is executed.

Comment: @Teemu: I've seen such solutions working. Why in the world I would not be able to scroll page after script execution?

Comment: @Teemu you could use `setInterval` so the function isn't called continuesly but periodicly ergo it is not blocking the UI. Or run it in a background worker. (depending on what's in the function). The isVisible part is a little trickier then Ahren is insinuating. Scrolling out of view is not detected by `:visible`. maybe [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/pdxjs/fO-3ApxbgRQ) will help

Comment: *was* insinuating, I deleted my answer after thinking it through properly... I agree on `setInterval` or `setTimeout` point.

Comment: That's right VDP, periodicly execution by setInterval() was what I have in mind.

Comment: @VDP I agree with your opinion, but in the question there was "continuously execute". Miloshio: I'm sorry, my comment was a bit poor, I meant: while script is executed, it freezes the browser. You can test this with a simple `while(true);` loop.

Comment: This is potentially a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling except for the "tab is changed" part. which is why I hesitate to click close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I know this is a bad method of answering. The standard is to close this question and point to the duplicate question, but this question has two parts and two separate answers. So, I'm putting the links to the answers here:

**Part 1: Detect when an HTML element is not in scroll view**

[Check if element is visible after scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487073/check-if-element-is-visible-after-scrolling)

**Part 2: Detect when tab is not in view**

[How to tell if browser/tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)

Both of the above seem to have working answers. Just implement both to get what you want.