# How to check if user is viewing the current tab/window?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the only thing I can think:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $([window, document]).focusin(function(){
    alert('hi');
  }).focusout(function(){
    alert('see you');
  });
```

But it doesn't work. It should show an alert when not viewing the page, and another one when viewing the page. Of course this is not my final application but it should work that way. Any suggestion?

jQuery is loaded, other actions inside `$(document).ready()` are working, no errors are shown...

Comment: Have you tried `focus` and `blur` instead? ...and you don't need to assign these in `$(document).ready()`. The `window` and `document` are immediately available.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Comment: see here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active

Comment: I'm sorry, didn't find that question when I searched. Thank you!