# JQUERY poll MYSQL db only if user is active

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I'm building an interactive page where a chatbox and a list of items appear.

I intend to update both of them every 30 seconds using JQUERY's .post() function, but I realize many users keep webpages opened in tabs 24 hours a day, creating a heavy load on the server.

In order to prevent this and to optimize my ressources, I would like the database polling to be executed every 30 seconds ONLY if the user is active on the page; in the passive cases, I would like a 5 minutes polling.

How can I achieve this? (I'm using PHP and MYSQL)

Comment: Define what you mean by "active".

Comment: First tell us what you use as backend.

Comment: @WooCaSh PHP and MYSQL

Comment: So it's all about how you define active. You could have some sort of timer counting down to set them as inactive, and anytime they scroll or focus an input, click, etc. you reset the count down.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to detect if a browser window is not currently active?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try detect cursor position changing.

1. On page load start setInterval method to send request to PHP
2. Add adittional setInterval to check if user cursor is moving
3. If not wait some time and then clear 1 interval.
4. If yes allow interval works normally.

I'm not sure how will work cursor position checking method if user go to other tab. I will prepare test for you (only js)

### EDIT:

W3C actually start working on `page visibility` as document attribute: http://www.w3.org/TR/page-visibility/

But for now is better solution. Look on this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1060034/390747

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can create a function that's based on the [onScroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll/) event? But I suppose that depends on what your definition of 'active' is.

Comment: Active means that the user is viewing the tab currently

Comment: I don't personally know a way of detecting that :(