# jquery detect if user change tab

Tags: jquery

I want to detect if user change the tab so the ajax requests stop. I tried with `$(window).focus(function() {` but it doesn't seems to work proper in my case. The problem is everything is stoped until you change the tab and return back to your site. And then even if you change the tabs again the requests don't pause. Any idea?

Comment: Please show all your code

Comment: yes , use `blur` : http://jsfiddle.net/cherniv/XALfC/

Comment: `The problem is everything is stoped until you change the tab and return back to your site.` thats what happens when using blur or focus

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if browser/tab is active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `blur` event:

```
$(window).on("blur", function() {
   // do whatever you want
});
```

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'on' `

Comment: when I change `on` with `bind` it works but why is it doubled? i think that cause the problem with ajax requests to not pause them.

Comment: Check your jQuery version if it supports `on` function. it is not doubled. It appears to be doubled because you are seeing an `iframe`. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/uX84X/show/ (its the same code)