# How to alert in title bar of browser on receiving a new message?

Tags: javascript, php

I have coded a simple chat application in php. I want to know that how to put a blinking title on title bar to notify a user that he received a new message if he is switched to other tab.
My codes:
 Javascript:

```
//messager fetcher

function reload_content() {



var xmlhttp;

if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("chatBox").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }

   xmlhttp.open("POST","messages.php",true);
xmlhttp.send();
    scrollToBottom();
}
window.setInterval(reload_content, 1000);
```

and code for messages.php

```
<?php


  //database connection starts
$con = mysql_connect("******","******","******");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }

mysql_select_db("chat", $con);
//database connection ends

$display_message = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `messages` WHERE `myname` = '$_SESSION[name]' or `friend` = '$_SESSION[name]'");
 if($display_message === FALSE) {
    die(mysql_error()); // TO DO: better error handling
}


     while($row_display=mysql_fetch_array($display_message))
        {


    $display=$row_display['msg'];
}
echo $display;
?>
```

Comment: Where is the condition that detects whether a new message has been received?

Answer (score 1):

Modify `document.title` (by assigning new values to it) repeatedly using `setInterval`.

You may wish to determine what the new value should be by taking the initial value and running regular expressions over it.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `document.title`?

Comment: @putvande — Yes … and that's what I typed when I was testing it. I should probably go back to bed.

Comment: i don't mean to change the title all the time only when a new message is received how can i do that?

Comment: @Webmasterpsb — You put the code to do it inside whatever code you use to determine if a new message has arrived.

Answer (score 1):

To detect if the user has switched to other tab, use this trick:

```
var isActive;

window.onfocus = function () { 
  isActive = true; 
}; 

window.onblur = function () { 
  isActive = false; 
}; 

// test
setInterval(function () { 
  console.log(window.isActive ? 'active' : 'inactive'); 
}, 1000);
```

*Source : https://stackoverflow.com/a/1760283/652669*

Then just update the title with:

```
document.title = 'message';
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the windows title in your javascript, there is an example here:

http://www.javascripter.net/faq/windowti.htm