# Javascript/JQuery Window Focus and Blur alternative

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus, blur

I know what `focus()` and `blur()` are, they respectively are that an element gets focus and an element loses focus. In my question I would like to talk about those events on the window object.

What I want is the following, alternatives to `focus(), blur()` that do the following:

- If the webpage is in the view of the client, then it should be `in focus`. Being in the view is defined as:

  - Normally looking at the webpage.
  - Having the webpage window in the view, but have focus on some other screen in the OS. For example you have Skype open, but the browser is still visible in the background.
- If the webpage cannot be seen by the client, then it should be `not in focus`. Defined as:

  - The user being in full screen mode in some other application.
  - The browser being completely overlapped by another (set of) applications.
  - The browser being on a different tab and thus not rendering the webpage visible.

What are the alternatives I could use to accomplish this behaviour?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell if browser/tab is active](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)

Comment: Looks interesting, and I don't think such thing could be done easily, but why would you want this? can you explain your reason, perhaps someone can give you an alternative

Comment: @AbuRomaïssae I am having a website that parses a log file live. And I would like it stop doing that when I'm 'not there', but I still want to see it when even the screen is half visible.

Comment: is it for you or for people visiting your webpage? if its just for you I suggest you make something simpler, perhaps using start/pause button otherwise, I'll be interested to know if you find such events :) but I fear you will have to deal with cross browser/platforms compatibility