# Auto refreshing the page when it is visited after some duration of time

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can it be possible to auto-refresh a page when visiting to its tab after some duration of time. I am asking in the case of opening many tabs in the browser and the tab where our web page is running need to be auto-refreshed when coming back to it from the other tab

Comment: bind a variable to window.onblur and then use wondow.onfocus to check for that variable and refresh the page

Answer (score 1):

You can try [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp).

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="30">
```

Refresh document every 30 seconds:

So try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active).

or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1060008/is-there-a-way-to-detect-if-a-browser-window-is-not-currently-active). may solve your problem.

Comment: I need to refresh the page only after the visit of its tab, not continuously after the time interval
thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Below code will do the trick

```
$(window).on('focus', function() { 
    /*your code*/
    setTimeout(function(){
        location.reload();//will reload your page
    },1000); //duration
});
```