# How to handle requestAnimationFrame with unactive tabs?

Tags: javascript

Currently I am calling on regular times window.requestAnimationFrame (every 2 minutes), but when the page is inactive chrome stops its execution and when it becomes active again all the previous calls are released at once

I would like to not call window.requestAnimationFrame when the tab is inactive, but a different function.

How can I check if the window.requestAnimationFrame is available to be executed?

I have searched in stackoverflow but didn't found an answer.

Thank you for your responses

Comment: It sounds like you shouldn't be using `requestAnimationFrame` at all.  What are you trying to do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active

Comment: @SLaks It is necessary, it's for making a custom animation at the end of each "rounds"

Comment: @TomSlick I tried this, unfortunately it is not working when chrome is in the background of other apps