# How to detect if a page has focus (onload)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please I'd like to count the time spent on a given page. In order to do this, I need to know when the page is opened in new tab, without focus and then start counting when the tab has focus.

```
$(window).focus(function() {
    window_focus = true;
}).blur(function() {
    window_focus = false;
});
```

The above works well when the has already loaded on a focused tab. How can I know when a page is fully loaded without focus.

Comment: Didn't quite get the question. What's the problem again?

Answer (score 0):

Use the setInterval for setting the tick on the focused page and clear it when it loses focus.

Duplicate of:
[How to tell if browser/tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)

Comment: On page load when the page is not focused on (ie, user opened the page in new tab), count begins. How do I detect that the user is not focused on the page and wait for user to focus on the page before starting count?