# JQuery, first window click, next focus

Tags: jquery, click, window, focus, blur

How can i first call function *click* and next *focus* the window in jQuery?
I tried:

```
$(window).click(function(){
    console.log(1);
});

$(document).focus(function(){
    console.log(2);
});

$(document).blur(function(){
    console.log(3);
});
```

but $(document).focus and .blur don't work

Code that I have, for example:

```
var isActive = false, wasClick = false;
$(window).click(function()
{
    if (!$(this).hasClass('button') && !$(this).hasClass('otherElement'))
    {
        isActive = false;
        wasClick = false;
        console.log('unactive varible');
    }
});

$(window).focus(function()
{
    if (wasClick) 
    {
        isActive = true;
        wasClick = false;
        console.log('focus');
    }
});

$(window).blur(function()
{
    if (isActive)
    {
        wasClick = true;
        isActive = false;
        console.log('blur');
    }
});

$('.button').click(function()
{
    isActive = true;
    console.log('button click');
});
```

I perform the following steps:

1. Click button
2. I click to other program in windows
3. I back to my page by click to background

Output console:

```
button click
blur
focus
unactive varible
```

I want:

```
button click
blur
unactive varible
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, the focus event isn't as reliable (at least not in all browsers) on the window object.
You can periodically check on the focus status of the page by using `document.hasFocus()`, but that's not entirely what you are looking for, I presume?

Comment: Ohh thanks, i don't think about this, but it work when i add it to $(window).focus :

    $(window).focus(function()
    {
        if (!document.hasFocus()) return false;
        if (wasClick) 
        {
            isActive = true;
            wasClick = false;
            console.log('focus');
        }
    });     Thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to be of help!

Comment: Ohh and this don't work. And this have some bugs.. sometimes bypasses document.hasFocus(), and when i example switch cards then blur and focus function run several times..

Comment: Haven't tested this myself, but a quick search returned this, which might be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active
Perhaps the second code part of the accepted anwer might work for you?

Comment: I read this, but i create something else. I have $(window).click and i want check result this function before $(window).focus - only if window was click (look code in the first post)

Comment: okey, I checked everything and document.hasFocus() work, but have sometimes bugs. Thanks for that