# Detect tab switch inside browser and application switch from the browser

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to know about the **visibility state** of the tab when user does the tab switch in a particular browser and when user does the application switch.(switching out from browser)

```
var visibilityState,
    activeTab = (function(){
        var stateKey, eventKey, keys = {
            hidden: "visibilitychange",
            webkitHidden: "webkitvisibilitychange",
            mozHidden: "mozvisibilitychange",
            msHidden: "msvisibilitychange"
        };
        for (stateKey in keys) {
            if (stateKey in document) {
                eventKey = keys[stateKey];
                break;
            }
        }
        return function(c) {
            if (c) document.addEventListener(eventKey, c);
            return !document[stateKey];
        }
    })();
activeTab(function() {
    visibilityState = activeTab();
});
```

uses

```
$(window).blur(function(){
    if(!visibilityState){
        console.log("Tab Switch happened ...");
    }
});
```

Comment: please add your code and what you tried so far

Answer (score 0):

What's your target browser support? Have you tried looking into the [Page Visibility API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Page_Visibility_API)? Or if you're using jQuery you can do `$(window).on("blur focus", someCallbackHere)` like how it's demonstrated in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active/1760268#1760268).