# Chrome Extension: How to simulate a mouse on focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

I am working on a Chrome Extension that works on a specific web page I have.
I need to simulate a mouse focus on a tab because I want to open a [calendar component](http://keith-wood.name/calendarsPickerRef.html) from the extension that only opens the calendar when the mouse is on focus on the page.
I tried with `chrome.tabs.update(TAB_ID, {"active": true}, function(tab){ });` with no success.
Please help!

Comment: Isn't `document.hidden` what you're looking for? Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active) (In regards to *I want to open a calendar component from the extension that only opens the calendar when the mouse is on focus on the page*)

Comment: I would use devtools to investigate the exact events used by the page and then I would dispatch synthetic events on the element that listens to those events like element.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent('xxx', {bubbles: true})) in your content script.

Comment: The calendar is using the on focus listener:
this.element.on("focus", function () {
   if (that.options.zindex != null) {
      $(".calendars-popup").css("z-index", that.options.zindex);
   }
   return true;});