# Music Keeps playing when i get off my browser

Tags: javascript, html

I have a mobile website that plays a background song. When I pressed the home button on my phone and leave the browser the song keeps playing until I go back on the browser and close the tab. 
this is the code for the song I have.

```
<audio preload="auto" src="song.mp3" loop="true" autobuffer id="myAudio">
Unsupported in Firefox
</audio>
```

How would I make it so the song only plays when I am viewing the page? Browser is Google Chrome and device is Android.

Comment: We need more information - which phone and browser specifically?

Comment: Google chrome on an android phone

Comment: try turning off preload="auto"

Comment: @ecg8`The preload attribute specifies if and how the author thinks that the audio file should be loaded when the page loads.` - Source: [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_audio_preload.asp).

Answer (score 0):

You could add an if condition in your javascript code which checks if your tab with the webpage is active and then play the music, else pause it check out

[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active)  stackoverflow question for checking if your tab is active