# window.focus/blur events in Blazor Web Assembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

Basically the scenario like in [How to tell if browser/tab is active](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760250/how-to-tell-if-browser-tab-is-active), but with Blazor Web Assembly. The idea in my case specifically is that when the Blazor app comes to the front, re-load data from the back end.

I haven't found any links to this specific scenario (most all Blazor & focus is about the now-solved setfocus problem). What is the best way to go about this when you have multiple pages in your Blazor app, and only one or a few of these want to react to focus/blur/document.hidden? JSInvokable from static to instance is going to be problematic if some pages don't have the functionality but others do. (my initial idea: a JS func "registerFocusEvent('mycallback')" that stores the string, on when focus happens, only call back to .NET when string is set)

Comment: What do you mean with "comes to the front"? How are you instantiating the component?

Comment: User creates a new tab or switches to another tab in the browser, and then comes back to the Blazor app.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a way other then JS interop. So what you can do ( based my work on the docs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-5.0#call-a-void-javascript-function) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/call-dotnet-from-javascript?view=aspnetcore-5.0#component-instance-method-call):

Add a JS Invokable update method in your razor component (i'm using `Index.razor`). Note, this is a bit weird, as the `JSInvokable` method needs to be static.

```cs
private static Func<Task> updateAsyncAction;
protected override void OnInitialized()
{
    base.OnInitialized();
    updateAsyncAction = async () => { await InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged); }; // triggers a rerender.
}

[JSInvokable]
public static async Task Update()
{
    await updateAsyncAction.Invoke();
}
```

Add a caller in a e.g. `wwwroot\Interop.js` file:

```js
window.IndexFunctions = {
    EnableOnFocusUpdate: function () {
        window.addEventListener("focus", function () {
            DotNet.invokeMethodAsync('{APP ASSEMBLY}', 'Update'); // The placeholder {APP ASSEMBLY} is the app's app assembly name.
        });
    }
}
```

In `index.html`, add the script before the closing body tag using

```html
<script src="Interop.js"></script>
```

Finally, you have to enable the js event listener in the razor page

```cs
@inject IJSRuntime JS
...
protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
{
    await base.OnAfterRenderAsync(firstRender);
    if (firstRender)
    {
        await JS.InvokeVoidAsync("IndexFunctions.EnableOnFocusUpdate");
    }
}
```

However, you need to click the blazor window once for this to start working... so maybe some more magic is needed.

edit: As noted in the comments, `Update` will remain registered even if you navigate away from the page, thus rerendering on focus. I'm not seeing an exception though, so in WASM it seems the object/instance is not destroyed.

It would be nice if a razor component would have some sort of `OnNavigateAway` or destructor, which we could use to remove the instance from `updateAsyncAction`. The best thing we can now do is do another JSInterop call using `removeEventListener`.
I will maybe ask this on the Blazor github.

Comment: Haven't tried it yet, but... if I navigate away from that Index, isn't the listener kept around? To stick with the boilerplate, if I go to counter, and do switch tab there, where would the call go to?

Comment: @christophwille good point! Need more code to remove the event listener. Would be nice to have a native blazor solution

Answer (score 0):

I have found a ready-made solution in https://github.com/zxyao145/BQuery/