# How to tell if user just navigated to the page or was waiting on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to register if user has been on the page for a while (waiting for some content to load) or has just came to a page..
What would be the best way to do that? I am using Rails and jquery.

Thanks

Comment: Duplicate (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/667555/detecting-idle-time-in-javascript-elegantly)

Comment: @GabrielSantos He's not detecting idle. Idle would imply they're doing nothing. He wants to detect if they are there (which doesn't necessarily mean they're idle)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All users will "come" to the page but if you want to be alerted after they're there for a specific amount of time you could set a timer to send an ajax request after a number of seconds.

For example, the following code would execute the function `inform` after every 5 seconds. Informing you that the user is still waiting...

```
setTimeout("inform()",5000);
```

The function `inform` would be an AJAX request which informs the backend that the user is waiting. If you only want the request to fire once or after a number of runs stop firing then you could remove it with `clearTimeout()`.

If you want the timeout to only run while the user is waiting on a specific piece of content to load. You could have the `clearTimeout()` execute when the content you expect will be delayed returns.

You can find some more info on timeouts [here.](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Javascript setTimeout ok for you?

It will kick off some code after however long you set it for.

Answer (score 0):

> You can watch [mouse movement](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/mousemove#fn), but that's about the best you're going
>   to get for indication of a user still being there without listening to
>   the click event. But there is no way for javascript to tell if it is
>   the active tab or if the browser is even open. (well, you could get
>   the width and height of the browser and that'd tell you if it was
>   minimized)

From https://stackoverflow.com/a/1009268/744255