# Javascript - Inactive user log out

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking for a really simple piece of javascript code that I can add to an html page that senses when a user has been inactive for 30 minutes, pops up a message for 1 minute and logs the user out of a web application if the user doesn't respond to keep the applcation open.

Thanks

Comment: 1) what have you tried? 2) please define what "inactive" means to you (e.g. mouse movement, key pressed...).

Comment: check out this question , I think it will help you  [How can I detect with JavaScript/jQuery if the user is currently active on the page?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009260/how-can-i-detect-with-javascript-jquery-if-the-user-is-currently-active-on-the-p

Comment: So far I have found this bit of code <script type="text/javascript">
var t;
window.onload=resetTimer;
document.onkeypress=resetTimer;

function logout()
{
 alert("You are now logged out.")
 location.href='logout.php' 
}
function resetTimer()
{
 clearTimeout(t);
 t=setTimeout(logout,1800000) //logs out in 30 minutes
}
</script>

Comment: The answer below is perfect! And should accept it. Say, you have a server side script that logs out the users. You just bind a call to that script to `idle.idleTimer`.E.g. 
`$.idleTimer(10000);
$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function()
{window.location = "logout.php";});`

Answer (score 2):

You can try with `idleTime`

Link : http://paulirish.com/2009/jquery-idletimer-plugin/

Sample :

```
$.idleTimer(100);
$(document).bind("idle.idleTimer", function()
{
    var reload = confirm("If you refresh your page ?");

    if (reload)
         location.reload(true);
    else
         window.location = "You log Out";

});
```