# JQuery Close Modal After Inactivity

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am creating a touch screen feedback kiosk that prompts users for their email address after they select a feedback option (good / bad).

Leaving their email address is optional, so the modal window should close after x seconds of inactivity.

How can I detect if a user is currently 'active' in the modal and close it if not (using JQuery)?

The countdown timer should be reset, and modal stay open if:

- The user begins to type in the input.

The modal should be closed if;

- The input has been inactive for x seconds (user leaves).

I have half of it complete, just need some help with the rest of it. Currently the timer only changes on each click of the input.

My current code is below;

[Here's a link](https://jsfiddle.net/johnny_s/xjm0z3f9/4/) to a my fiddle.

**HTML**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="feedbackFormBad">click</button>
<div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="memberNumberModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
        <h1>Hello</h1>
      </div>
      <div align="center" class="modal-body">
        <p>Some text here.</p>
        <p span id="countdown"></p>
        <!-- show count down timer here -->
        <form id="memberNumberForm" class="form-inline">
          <div class="form-group mb-2">
            <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" id="memberNumber" placeholder="enter email" required>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">No Thanks</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#feedbackFormBad").on("touchstart, click", function(e) {
    $('#memberNumberModal').modal('toggle');
    var counter = 5;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
      $("#memberNumber").focus(function() {
        $("#countdown").html('Window will close in ' + counter + ' seconds.');
      });

      if (counter == 0) {
        $('#memberNumberModal').modal('hide');
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
});
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/1009413/3126973

Answer (score 3):

Try with the below javascript code

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#feedbackFormBad").on("touchstart, click", function(e) {
    $('#memberNumberModal').modal('toggle');
    var counter = 5;
    var interval = setInterval(function() {
      counter--;
      $("#countdown").html('Window will close in ' + counter + ' seconds.');

      if (counter == 0) {
        $('#memberNumberModal').modal('hide');
        clearInterval(interval);
      }
    }, 1000);
    $('body').bind('mousedown keydown', function(event) {
       counter = 5;
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<body>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="feedbackFormBad">click</button>
  <hr>
  <p>The timer should be reset if:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>The user begins to type in the input.</li>
  </ul>
  <p>The modal should be closed if:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>The input has been inactive for x seconds (user leaves).</li>
  </ul>
  <div aria-hidden="true" class="modal fade" id="memberNumberModal" role="dialog" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header modal-header-primary">
          <h1>Hello</h1>
        </div>
        <div align="center" class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text here.</p>
          <p span id="countdown"></p>
          <!-- show count down timer here -->
          <form id="memberNumberForm" class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group mb-2">
              <input type="text" name="Email" class="form-control" id="memberNumber" placeholder="enter email" required>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="closeModal" data-dismiss="modal">No Thanks</button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Resetting of the counter on an event might work and hopefully it meets your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a combination of `setInterval` and `all of the events` to achieve this. I've commented the code below.

## Update

Originally, I'd posted an answer using the `keyup` function - missing the *touchscreen* part of the requirements. However, the below listens for any change to the text input. Let me know if this works.

The events were taken from this answer here 
[Best way to track onchange as-you-type in input type="text"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/574941/best-way-to-track-onchange-as-you-type-in-input-type-text?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

```js
// Keep track of if user is active
var active = true;

// keep track of how long since the user has typed
var timeElapsed = 0;

// check every second
setInterval(function(){
  timeElapsed += 1;
  
  // example
  $("#timer").html(timeElapsed + " seconds inactive");
  
  // a minute has passed since the user has typed
  if(timeElapsed == 60){
    // close modal
    $('#memberNumberModal').modal('hide');
  }
}, 1000);

// if the user types, reset the timer
$("#test").on('change keydown paste input propertychange click keyup blur', function(){
  // user is active, has typed
  timeElapsed = 0;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input id="test" type="text">
<span id="timer"></span>
```

Comment: If this works, and you don't want all of those events, perhaps you could remove them one by one until you find the ones that do work.