# JavaScript: setInterval function counts only when browser is idle?

Tags: javascript, php

I want to logout properly when browser is inactive with ***setInterval()*** 
function. When browser is active, setInterval is not counting. However, when browser stays idle then the function is counting.

How do I achieve setInterval counting even browser is active?

**JavaScript**

```
function session_checking() {
    $.post("activitytime.php");
}   
*//Every after 7 mins (60*7) after browser is inactive run activitytime.php*'   
setInterval(session_checking, 1000*10);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
//Do the necessary database update
session_destroy();
```

Comment: Best practice would be to check and invalidate the session on backend when the user reloads the page. Javascript could be simply blocked through developer's console.

Comment: `When browser is active, setInterval is not counting` why isn't it counting? it should be calling session_checking every 10 seconds regardless. And what does it mean by the browser is `active` or `idle`

Comment: Use session timeout, not javascript.  [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1270960/7644018)

Comment: @JaromandaX I assume he means no mouse movement, no typing and no scrolling... OP also disregards the fact, that javascript can't tell if the right tab is open. Seems like duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009260/how-can-i-detect-with-javascript-jquery-if-the-user-is-currently-active-on-the-p)

Comment: @AlexKarshin - I don't assume to know anything other than what is stated in the question - OP alleges the setTimeout isn't running while the browser is `active` - that makes zero sense, hence why I asked what he means by active and idle

Comment: True, I read it very carefully once more and now it makes zero sense to me too. Sorry for misleading you like that :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I detect with JavaScript/jQuery if the user is currently active on the page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1009260/how-can-i-detect-with-javascript-jquery-if-the-user-is-currently-active-on-the-p)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ´window´ events and ´clearInterval´

```
var sessionTimer;

function startTimer(){
      sessionTimer = setInterval(session_checking, 1000*10);
}
function stopTimer(){
    if(sessionTimer){
        clearInterval(sessionTimer);
    }
}
function session_checking() {
     $.post("activitytime.php");
} 
//means tab is active
window.onfocus = function () { 
   stopTimer(); 
}; 
//means tab is passive
window.onblur = function () { 
    startTimer();
};
```

Also if you want to call API when window is closing you can call

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
      //call api here
      return true;
};
```